# How do I parse the Gemfile to find internal gems not inside a source block?

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

For the sake of security internal Ruby gems in the `Gemfile` should always be referenced inside a `source` block so it never tries to fetch them from rubygems.org.  I'd like to automate finding where people fail to do this, so would like to parse the `Gemfile`, find any gems that match our internal names, and check that rubygems.org isn't in their possible sources list.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem 'my-private-gem1' # this should be in the source block below

source PRIVATE_GEM_REPO do
  gem 'my-private-gem2'
end
```

I've seen you can parse the `Gemfile`

```
Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile', '', {})
```

But can't find anything in the returned data structure that shows me the available / allowed sources per gem

If I include the `Gemfile.lock` I see more source info, but it doesn't seem right because every gem lists all my sources regardless of if they're in a source block

```
Bundler::Definition.build('Gemfile', 'Gemfile.lock', {}).
  locked_gems.
  specs.
  map {|g| [g.full_name, g.source.remotes.map(&:hostname).join(', ')]}
=> ["rails-6.0.3.4", "my.private.gemserver, rubygems.org"],
   ["my-private-gem1-1.0.0", "my.private.gemserver, rubygems.org"],
   ["my-private-gem2-1.0.0", "my.private.gemserver, rubygems.org"]]
```

Any thoughts on how to parse the `Gemfile` to find that `my-private-gem1` is outside a source block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally, just took awhile digging through the Bundler methods - and a coworker's help.

```
Bundler::Definition.
  build('Gemfile', '', nil).
  dependencies.
  map {|dep| [dep.name, dep.source&.remotes&.map(&:hostname)&.join(', ')]}
=>
[["rails", nil],
 ["my-private-gem1", nil],
 ["my-private-gem2", "my.private.gemserver"]]
```

Now I can easily search that resulting data structure for any private gems that aren't locked down to my private gem server.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

While I was writing this answer, the OP found a Bundler-specific answer. However, I offer a more generalizable solution below. This solution also offers user feedback that may make it easier to fix the file.

### Finding Candidate Gems by Column Alignment, with Whitelisting

If you can safely assume that your Gemfile is always properly indented, the KISS solution may be to simply identify the gems that aren't indented within a group definition. For example:

```rb
# example Gemfile to test against
GEMFILE = <<~'EOF'
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rails'
  gem 'my-private-gem1' # this should be in the source block below
  source PRIVATE_GEM_REPO do
    gem 'my-private-gem2'
  end
EOF

# gems that are acceptable in a non-group context
whitelist = Regexp.new %w[rails sass-rails webpacker].join(?|)

UngroupedGem   = Struct.new :line_no, :line_txt, :gem_name
ungrouped_gems = []

GEMFILE.lines.each_with_index do |line_txt, line_no|
  next if line_txt =~ whitelist or line_txt !~ /^\s*gem/
  gem_name = line_txt.match(/(?<=(['"]))(.*?)(?=\1)/)[0]
  ungrouped_gems.append(
    UngroupedGem.new line_no.succ, line_txt, gem_name
  ).compact!
end

# tell the user what actions to take
if ungrouped_gems.any?
  puts "Line No.\tGem Name"
  ungrouped_gems.each { printf "%d\t\t%s\n", _1.line_no, _1.gem_name }
else
  puts "No gems need to be moved."
end
```

With this example, it will print:

> ```
> Line No.  Gem Name
> 3         my-private-gem1
> 5         my-private-gem2
> ```

which will give you a solid idea of what lines in the Gemfile need to be moved, and which specific gems are involved.